# How to accumulate aggregate group by nested object keys in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

I am looking for an aggregate pipeline in MongoDB which can achieve this requirement:

I have a collection like:

```
  {"filter": {
    "_id": {
      "$gt": 10
    }
   }
  },
  {"filter": {
    "_id": {
      "$gt": 20
    }
   }
  },
  {"filter": {
    "_id": {
      "$lt": 30
    }
   }
  },
  {"filter": {
    "name": {
      "first": 'Lee'
    }
   }
  },
  ...
```

A filter field is a nested object defined in my collection. I want to find a way to accumulate all nested keys in the `filter` field. Take above as an example, I want to get the result:

```
_id.$gt: 2
_id.$lt: 1
name.first:1 
...
```

the key in the result list is the nested keys defined in `filter` and the value is the number of duplicates of the nested keys.